# Hide a mapView and remove blank space

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this view in my project [image]

When the Location Description is not filled in, I need the mapView to be hidden but I am not able to fill in the white space when this is done. Can anybody help me? I tried to add an IBoutlet of the height and make the set with:

```
_mapViewHeighConstraint.constant = 0.0;
```

Unfortunately I could not make it work.

Comment: Is this a static view or is this some kind of tableView with custom cells?

Comment: @Prientus it's a static view. I'm use ScrollView and UIView in sections to arrange layout

Comment: Alrighty. Then I would suggest you do the same thing you did with the mapViewHeight constraint but instead of the map itself, add the constraint in the container UIView that holds the mapView. Would that work?

Comment: @Prientus Try do this but isn't successful ):